# what is this injection query looks like?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, sqlmap

what might be the mysql query  if

1. mysql injected it with `'#` only for username and password blank
2. logged in as admin

how to get mysql info using this injection ?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking for. You have seen an injection working with '# and you are now wondering what was the injectable query? Does bullet 2 mean the injection worked and logon as admin was achieved? What exactly do you mean by "mysql info"?